# Initialize two Python classes with same arguments, get different results

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, serial-port

**Objective:** understand strange behavior regarding two classes initialized with identical arguments, and producing different results.

**Background:**

My project involves a Raspberry Pi 3 communicating with various sensors on an Arduino MEGA via serial (through the USB port) communication. The communication protocol is simple.

The Raspberry Pi sends two bytes:

1. The address of the sensor (e.g. `'\x04'`)
2. A second empty byte that can contain additional commands (e.g. `'\x00'`)

The MEGA waits for two bytes, and then replys with the requested information based on a large `case/switch` tree.

I have encapsulated the code for handling various sensors withing Python `class`es. The one that is giving me trouble is the `Encoder()` class. Here is a minimal example:

```
import serial

class Encoder(object):
    def __init__(self, hex_name):
        self.hex_name = hex_name

    def value(self):
        temp = self.hex_name + '\x00'
        arduino.write(temp)
        return int(arduino.readline())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACMO', 115200)

    encoder_one = Encoder('\x03')
    encoder_two = Encoder('\x04')

    print encoder_one.value()
    print encoder_two.value()
```

The Arduino handles the request as shown below:

```
if(Serial.available() >= 2){
    temp1 = Serial.read();
    temp2 = Serial.read();

    switch(temp1){
        case 1:
          ...
        case 3:
            Serial.println(positionLeft);
            break;
        case 4:
            Serial.println(positionRight);
            break;
        case 5:
         ...
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

I get nonsensical values from the encoders. Particularly concerning is that when I initialize both encoder with the *same* hex_name (i.e. `'\x04'`), I get different values from `encoder_one.value()` and `encoder_two.value()`.

**Hypothesis:**

1. Something about the class structure is wrong.

I had this working alright before I encapsulated it in a class. I wondered if I was assigning `encoder_one` and `encoder_two` to the same object or something silly like that.

I added a line just before `return` in `value()` that would print the `hex_name` (i.e. `print self.hex_name`). When I set both encoders to `'\x04'` I get the same non-alphanumeric character printed. When I set one encoder to `'\x03'` and the other to `'\x04'` I get two different non-alphanumeric characters--one being the character from the previous test.

2. Frame-shift in the communication.

The MEGA is expecting two bytes. It waits for two bytes, sends the requested information, then clears the buffer. Is is possible that storing the hex values as string in my Python program, a extra byte is getting added when it performs `arduino.write()`. Something like a `\n` or other non-printable character.

**Conclusion:**

I've put about three hours into this bug, and I think solving it requires some information about how classes work that I do not understand.

Comment: Did you really mean to have the `if` inside the class definition?

Comment: you probably meant `temp = self.hex_name + '\x00'` in your function

Comment: `int(arduino.readline())` implies that `arduino.readline()` is returning data as a string of text bytes, terminated with a newline, eg `'42\n'`. Is that correct, or is it returning binary data, like `'\x2A'`?

Comment: My Arduino responds to a request with `Serial.println(positionRight)`, so I believe that would be a string. I will add more details about how the Arduino processes the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be the second hypothesis. There is apparently some non-printable character being included in the concatenation step of the hex bytes. Switching to the following order solved the problem.

**EDIT:** I discovered that performing a `readline()` immediately after `write()` was giving intermitent errors. I added a 10 ms delay between the two operations.

**Old:**

```
def value(self):
    temp = self.hex_name + '\x00'
    arduino.write(temp)
    return int(arduino.readline())
```

**New:**

```
def value(self):
    arduino.write(self.hex_name)
    arduino.write('\x00')
    time.sleep(0.010)
    return int(arduino.readline())
```

The complete (now working) example is shown below.

```
import serial

class Encoder(object):
    def __init__(self, hex_name):
        self.hex_name = hex_name

    def value(self):
        arduino.write(self.hex_name)
        arduino.write('\x00')
        time.sleep(0.010)
        return int(arduino.readline())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACMO', 115200)

    encoder_one = Encoder('\x03')
    encoder_two = Encoder('\x04')

    print encoder_one.value()
    print encoder_two.value()
```

Comment: As the solution to this problem turned out to be slightly different than I had thought when I originally posted the question (and decided on its title), should I now delete it?